# how to update cell in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have datagridview that connect to my database (access)

if i stay on any cell and change the value, a see that the value is changed

but when i make refresh i see that the value is back to the original value.

how i can update this cell (without sql query)

i bind dataset to datagridview like this:

```
dsView = new DataSet();
            adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Items", Conn);
            adp.Fill(dsView, "Items");
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dsView.Tables["Items"].DefaultView;
            adp.Dispose();
```

please, i must find how to do it.....

thank's in advance

Comment: You will have to provide much better details on the objects bound and what you are actually trying to update without going to the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your datagridview is connected to the database and you do not want to use SQL, i can suppose it is bound to a datasource. If you performed that through the Visual Studio Designer there should be a `TableAdapter` (if automatically generated, probably called *YOURTABLENAMETableAdapter*) and a `BindingSource` (if automatically generated, probably called *YOURTABLENAMEBidingSource*).

To update your database you will have to call BindingSource.EndEdit() and then TableAdapter.Update(). After you have done this, you can refresh your data.

**EDIT**

Now that you have provided better information i can give you a better answer.
In my previous answer, I assumed that you created everything with the designer because you didn't want to use SQL to make the update. Obviously i was wrong.

To achieve what you are looking for, you should use the [`OleDbCommandBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder.aspx) Class which, given a `SELECT` command, automatically generates simple editing command (insert/update/delete) for your table.

here is an example using your code:

```
dsView = new DataSet();
adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Items", Conn);
OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adp);
adp.Fill(dsView, "Items");
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dsView.Tables["Items"].DefaultView;
//adp.Dispose(); You should dispose you adp only when it is not loger needed (eg: after performing the update)
```

Now, after you perfomed your changes to the data you can call

```
adp.Update(dsView, "Items");
```

Comment: i try this: dataGridView2.EndEdit();
            dataGridView2.Update();  but it dont work

Comment: No, that's wrong. You have to use the bound object. Somewhere in your code there is the assigment dataGridView.DataSource = somethingBindingSource (probably in the form.Designer.cs file) and that is your BindingSource (the one to call EndEdit() on). You will also find a somethingTableAdapter to call the Update. How did you perform the binding between the datagrid and you Db?

Comment: i still dont Understand, i update my question - how i work with database

Comment: thank's for the help, now i got this error: Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

Comment: Did you set a primary key in your table?