# Automatically Update DataSet if there is a Change in SQL Server Table in VB.Net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, dataset, database-connection

I am wondering if it is possible to automatically update DataSet whenever there is a change in an SQL Server Table. I think a new/updtate record event handler from SQL server that transmits a signal to VB.net application which in turn refreshes the connection to the SQL server and refill the table in the DataSet. Not really sure if this is possible.

Comment: Do a `Google` search for `SqlDependency`, exactly what you would need. It actually uses ServiceBroker behind the scenes to process the changes and when something changes your application is notified of these changes. If you want to go the Service Broker route you then need to handle your own messages and queues, it is not difficult, but something you probably do not want to start with.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022915/how-to-update-cell-in-datagridview

Comment: @Verdolino the link you provide doesn't come close to helping the OP with his question. Of course you can update the `DataSet` and such, but does not address ***if theres a change in the SQL server***. In general data adapters and builders ***can not watch a server instance (table) for changes***.

Comment: I posted a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Zaggler thanks for your comment `SQLDependency` was exactly what I am looking for, hopefully i can get my head wrapped around it fairly quickly

Comment: @user1704812 you are welcome, there are many examples around that can have you up and going fairly quickly.